# i want have two different buttons having different functionality in flask app

Tags: html, flask

[when i click the upload button it will direct us to another html page where it will ask to upload the file]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7GkT.png)https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8zf8.png

So the problem is that i've made a flask app where there are two buttons.
Button 1) we can upload a csv file through it
Button 2) we can fill a form in it

When i'm clicking the button it it going to the respective html pages. But while clicking the
upload button or submit form. It is unable to do that.

I've attached the image link  in the description.

This is my code so far.

```
import glob  
import os  
import warnings  
import csv    
import xlsxwriter

import jsonpickle
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config.from_object(__name__) 

@app.route('/')  
def index():  
    return render_template('button.html')

@app.route('/upload')             
def upload():          
    return render_template('upload.html')

def allowed_CV_file(filename):
    #code for only uploading csv file

@app.route("/uploader", methods=['GET','POST'])
def uploader():
    #whatever the function is to upoad the file in path

@app.route('/form_fill')    
def form_fill():
    return render_template('jdfillupform.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('0.0.0.0' , 8089 , debug=False , threaded=True)
```

Comment: You need to show us the html so we know what the button does.

Comment: The home screen buttons are working fine. But while uploading the file it is not happening. That functionality i've kept in flask file itself @atultw

Comment: You commented out the whole file upload part. If the issue is with file upload, show us that code please. Remember to ask a good question include the expected outcome and what happened instead, including any errors.